# How to change value of field in Angular formGroup

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to change value of field "send_diagnostic_data" in another function, how can I make it?

```
private createForm(): void {
  this.messageForm = new FormGroup({
    message: new FormControl(''),
    date: new FormControl(new Date()),
    messageType: new FormControl('sent'),
    send_diagnostic_data: new FormControl(false),
  });
}
```

Comment: Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and improve your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

```
this.messageForm.get('send_diagnostic_data').setValue(false);
```